# meaning of the phrase "silent health"?

Tags: meaning

It is from [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/_XPZQ0LAlR4). It is at around 7 minute and 36 second. Here it goes:

> "Though ten out of twelve had fallen, still the last two, as sure as death, were to be found on the first evening of rest over the bottle drinking a **silent health** to their dead companions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To

> **drink to** ***someone's*** **health**

is to toast someone and acknowledge them.

What the writer is saying is the remaining two were having silent *(and sobering)* drink in memory of the ten that had fallen.